# How to cluster the nodes of the Cora dataset based on their in-degree values?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to cluster the nodes of Cora dataset in a way that each cluster only contains the nodes with the same in-degree value. I can code something as follows:

```
import torch
from torch_geometric.datasets import Planetoid
from torch_geometric.utils import degree

dataset = Planetoid('./data','CORA')
data = dataset[0]
n = data.num_nodes
indegree = degree(data.edge_index[1], n, dtype=torch.long)
counts = torch.bincount(indegree)
```

But since I don't access the index value of the nodes, I don't know how to place each node in which cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return_inverse` in `torch.unique` to recover the indices.
The nodes with the same value `i` in `indices` belong to the same cluster because they all have a degree equal to `indegree_class[i]`.

```
indegree_class, indices = torch.unique(indegree, return_inverse=True)
```